# Print pattern using for loops

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application

How to print a pattern using for loops?

```
Figure(3)          Figure(4)

   **                  **
    **                  **
     **                  **
      **                  **
                           **
```

I tried this:

```
static void PrintPattern (int column)
{
    for (int r = 0; r <= column + 1; r++)
    {
        Console.Write("**");
        for (int c = 0; c < r; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please redo your question

Comment: Do you get any errors? see this for more help http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article2028-getting-different-shapes-of-stars-using-for-loops.aspx

Comment: im pretty sure this doesn't even compile. what is that <br> doing after the for?

Comment: I'm guessing ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** is Figure(3). What is Figure(4)?

Comment: See the edit guys it was just the OP's unfamiliar with the stack editor

Comment: seems like a `Homework` question related to `for statement`

Comment: Do you need this **only** using `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

made for fun, hope I won't receive too many -1s

```
int depth = 4;
var rows = Enumerable.Range(0, depth + 1)
                     .Select(v => new string('\t', v) + "**" );

var oneString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows);

Console.WriteLine (oneString);
```

prints:

```
**
  **
    **
      **
        **
```

Remarks:
 if you use `' '` as separator, instead of tab `'\t'`, you'll get next result:

```
**
 **
  **
   **
    **
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    void Main()
    {
        const int rowCount = 10;
        Console.Write("**");
        for (var rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < rowCount - 1; rowNumber++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n ");
            for (var spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < rowNumber; spaceCount++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.Write("**");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine . . .

> for figure3 : lines = 4,
>  for figure4 : lines = 5

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int lines = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++)
            {
                if (j == i)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("**");
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!flag)
                        Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - care to share ?

Comment: yes, sure, but It didn't actually answer the question, because OP want strictly `for` loop. Sorry If I took it wrong.

Comment: well i would like your answer, pls do share!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# but i'll help you in Java. You should change syntax as desired (`Console.Write` == `System.out.print` && `Console.Writeline` == `System.out.println`). So here goes the code:

```
 static void printPattern(int column){
   int spaceCount = 2;//number of spaces before **, change as needed
   int k;//number of times ** is printed each row, must remain always 1
   for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
       System.out.println();//starts each row with a new line
       for(int j = 1; j < spaceCount; j++){
           System.out.print(" ");//prints j spaces in each row
        }
        spaceCount++;//increment spacecount each row, so j can also go + 1 
        for(k = 1; k <= 1; k++){
            System.out.print("**");//each row prints ** k times
        }
        k--;//k must remain 1
    }
}
```

For Figure(3) call `printPattern(4);` for Figure(4) `printPattern(5);`